# Multiple Locations Google Map - title in bubble not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have multiple locations on Google map that work fine. I display the title for each location in a bubble. The problem is when I insert apostrophe into the title" ' ". Then it stops working. I have tried to replace the apostrophe " ' " with '. This fixes the problem but also display the ' in the title. My current code is:

```
 function initialize(){
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var locations = [
            <cfoutput query="qryOutletPostcodes">
                <cfhttp url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=#postcode#&sensor=false" result="myResult">
                <cfset cfData=DeserializeJSON(myResult.filecontent)>

                <cfset lat= #cfData.results[1].geometry.location.lat# >
                <cfset lng= #cfData.results[1].geometry.location.lng# >

                /* [ '<a href="outlets/###id#">#title#</a>', #lat#,#lng#], 
                [ '<a href="outlets/###id#">#htmlEditFormat(replace(title, "'", "&apos;", "all"))#</a>', #lat#,#lng#], */
                [ '<a href="outlets/###id#">#htmlEditFormat(replace(title, "'", "&apos;", "all"))#</a>', #lat#,#lng#],
            </cfoutput>
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng( 51.508742, -0.107346),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    });
```

[image]

Is there a way to fix this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would doing a `replace("'", "\'")` on the title before you use it work?

Comment: Great. That solved the problem. Thank you. The final code in ColdFusion: #htmlCodeFormat(replace(title, "'", "\'", "all"))#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```
replace("'", "\'")
```

You simply need to escape the apostrophe within the string.

*Edit* Sorry didn't read the comments and notice it was answered. Will leave this in place for future Googlers.

Comment: As well as replacing single quotes, you should replace slash with double slash first, otherwise a single slash will cause things to fail also, and can be a security risk, depending on the source of your data (XSS).